# In mongoose, how can I calculate data in one model of second model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want all students data in frontend and I am achieving it successfully. But before sending it to frontend I want to send count of each individual students that present in a one subject.

Attendance.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const AttendanceSchema = new Schema(
  {
    date: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Provide Date"],
      maxlength: 15,
      minlength: 5,
    },
    subjectID: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Subject",
      required: [true, "Please Provide Subject"],
    },
    studentID: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Student",
        required: [true, "Please Provide Student"],
      },
    ],
    teacherID: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Faculty",
      required: [true, "Please Provide Teacher"],
    },
    classID: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Class",
      required: [true, "Please Provide Class"],
    },
    departmentID: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Department",
      required: [true, "Please Provide Department"],
    },
  },

  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Attendance", AttendanceSchema);
```

Student.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Provide Name"],
      maxlength: 100,
      minlength: 2,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Provide Email"],
      match: [
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
        "Please Provide a Valid Email",
      ],
      unique: true,
    },
    number: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Provide Number"],
      match: [
        /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/,
        "Please Provide a Valid Number",
      ],
      unique: true,
    },
    rollNumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "Please Provide Roll Number"],
      maxlength: 5,
    },
    departmentID: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Department",
      required: [true, "Please Provide departmentID"],
    },
    classID: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Class",
      required: [true, "Please Provide classID"],
    },
    position: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Provide Position"],
      enum: ["Student"],
      default: "Student",
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Provide Password"],
      minlength: 6,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

In this function how can I check count and add it to each individual student object. First I tried with the for loop but it is not a good approach.

```
const getAllStudentOfClass = async (req, res) => {
  if (
    req.user.position == "Principle" ||
    req.user.position == "HOD" ||
    req.user.position == "Teacher"
  ) {
    const data = await StudentSchema.find({ classID: req.params.id });
    if (data == 0) {
      throw new NotFoundError("There is no Student in this Class");
    }
    const subject = await AttendanceSchema.find({
    subjectID: req.params.Sid,
     }).select("studentID");
if (subject !== 0) {
for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        Object.defineProperty(data[j], "classAttained", {
          value: 0,
          writable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true,
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < subject.length; i++) {
          for (let k = 0; k < subject[i].studentID.length; k++) {
            console.log(subject[i].studentID[k]);
            if (subject[i].studentID[k].toString() == data[j]._id.toString()) {
              data[j].classAttained = +1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ data });

  } else {
    throw new UnauthenticatedError("Unauthenticate User");
  }
};
```

This is how my data is stored in attendance.
[image: This is how my data is stored in attendance.]

This type of data I am getting from student query.
I want to check how many times one student is present in this subject array and add that count to the data which we will send it to frontend.
like this: The below is the desired output.

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("635ab4311af835d58b2b385d"),
    count:5 // No. of times he/she is present in that subject
    name: 'D R',
    email: 'd@gmail.com',
    number: '9198999999',
    rollNumber: 201,
    departmentID: new ObjectId("635989a90711cff3dd034dfb"), 
    classID: new ObjectId("63599d9edb142671844297d6"),      
    position: 'Student',
    createdAt: 2022-10-27T16:39:13.544Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-10-27T16:39:13.544Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("635ab4311af835d58b2b385d"),
    count:5 // No. of times he/she is present in that subject
    name: 'R R',
    email: 'r@gmail.com',
    number: '9198988999',
    rollNumber: 202,
    departmentID: new ObjectId("635989a90711cff3dd034dfb"), 
    classID: new ObjectId("63599d9edb142671844297d6"),      
    position: 'Student',
    createdAt: 2022-10-27T16:39:13.544Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-10-27T16:39:13.544Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

and this is subjects data

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("636026666d5ea5f180e68719"),
    studentID: [ new ObjectId("635ab4311af835d58b2b385d") ] 
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("636178226d5ea5f180e6871d"),
    studentID: [ new ObjectId("635ab4311af835d58b2b385d") ] 
  }
]
```